# Trix Editor Showing on Localhost but not Heroku (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, trix

I just updated my app to Rails 5.2 and subsequently switched to Trix Editor for my WYSIWYG.  It's working just fine on localhost:

[image]

But doesn't show up on Heroku:

[image]

I have the following code on my show page:

```
  <%= f.label "Joke" %>
  <%= f.trix_editor :body %>
```

And have included these requires in my `application.scss`:

```
 *= require magnific-popup
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require recurring_select
 *= require simple_calendar
 *= require trix
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

With this in my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require magnific-popup
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require recurring_select
//= require trix
//= require_tree .
```

I can't figure out where the disconnect here is.  I do have to precompile assets locally before I deploy to Heroku, but I have, so that can't be it.  Can anyone see what asset pipeline weirdness is going on?

Comment: You should be using [`@import` instead of `*= require`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) in your scss files (not sure if it will correct your issue though)

Comment: @MarkMerritt Yes!  That (alongside a recompiling of the assets) did the trick!  Thank you!